# Automatic upload of photos to OneDrive

Tags: 8.0, onedrive, photos

I've just been comparing my Camera Roll on my phone with my OneDrive > Pictures > Camera Roll folder, and now have some questions:

- Despite having autoupload on (Best Quality), only 101 of my 264 photos have been uploaded.  Having a quick Google hasn't shown any limits on size or any other reason why photos wouldn't be uploaded - is there something I've missed?
- Under the "Best quality" option, photos seem to be uploaded at full resolution / size - is this correct?

I've also got the CloudSix for Dropbox app, with autoupload also enabled, and this has only not uploaded one photo - this photo doesn't display a thumbnail in the Camera Roll folder when my phone is connected to my computer, but does open correctly - I assume there's a minor error with the file which led to the file not being uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

If your connection is on/off constantly, some photo uploads might be stuck in the upload queue.

Open the Photos up, click the three dots and choose "Upload status".

This is a bit annoying if you on a trip because there is no all to retry/requeue all failed uploads at once.

Comment: but when you get on wifi, they will all upload themselves without your help

Comment: That is how it's supposed to work but once they are added to the queue and fail, they cant get stuck. I've had pictures sitting in the upload queue after I was on stable for several days constantly.

Comment: I've never had that happen with wifi, though I have with cellular and just uploaded them one at a time.

Comment: Hmm, it says "No uploads at the moment", even though they're still not all in OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

For uploads to work at the Best Quality, WiFi is a must. Stay at a WiFi area until all the pictures are uploaded. Should probably take a while since you've got a lot of them left.

You can go to the upload queue and forcefully retry an upload, but again, you need to be in a WiFi area.